# Issue connecting to Windows OpenSSH with VS Code Remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, openssh, vscode-remote

Can connect fine via a regular terminal, but it looks like something is hanging maybe when it tries to set up everything on the server (it never does create the vscode folder as far as I can tell). This is our first time trying VS code SSH with a windows server, have always been able to deal with Linux. I've tried increasing the user SSH timeout settings.

```
[10:04:20.605] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": undefined
[10:04:20.605] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[10:04:20.605] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[10:04:20.605] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[10:04:20.605] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[10:04:20.605] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[10:04:20.606] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[10:04:20.606] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[10:04:20.606] SSH Resolver called for host: windowshost
[10:04:20.606] Setting up SSH remote "windowshost"
[10:04:20.620] Using commit id "2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8" and quality "stable" for server
[10:04:20.623] Install and start server if needed
[10:04:21.779] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[10:04:21.807] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[10:04:21.813] Remote command length: 5988/8192 characters
[10:04:21.813] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 59215 "acba-cv" powershell
[10:04:21.814] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:06:23.838] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at Function.Timeout (c:\Users\Joren\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.3\out\extension.js:1:64767)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\Joren\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.3\out\extension.js:1:412785)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
[10:06:23.857] ------
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried different settings including changing the remote-ssh configurations, windows ssh version and backend server configurations, but nothing worked.

After a complete reinstallation of vscode (removing all vscode-related files), everything worked again.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30590732)

Comment: pretty sure this is an answer